# In flutter I can not put the drawer under the appBar and keep the menu icon when the drawer and the arrow.left are closed when it is open

Tags: java, android, flutter, draw, appbar

In flutter I can not put the drawer under the appBar and keep the menu icon when the drawer and the arrow.left are closed when it is open

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        body: new Scaffold(
            key: _scaffoldKey, drawer: new MyDrawer()),
        appBar: new AppBar(
          leading: new IconButton(
                        icon: icon,
            onPressed: () { _handleDrawer();
              //Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
            },
          ),
          automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
          title: Text('Prospectos'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: (Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white)),
                iconSize: 36.0,
                onPressed: null,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: (Icon(Icons.local_bar, color: Colors.white)),
                iconSize: 36.0,
                onPressed: null,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: (Icon(Icons.cached, color: Colors.white)),
                iconSize: 36.0,
                onPressed: null,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: See [ask]. Don't just drop a blob of unformatted code here and expect someone to debug it for you. Tell us what you want to do, show what you tried, and show the results and research you've done.

Comment: Yes, and please include a photo or video/gif of your issue to help us understand this.